# powershell export csv add header?

Tags: powershell

```
 $employees = @()

#Add newly created object to the array
#$employees += $employee
for ($i=1;$i -le 2;$i++)
{
    $employee = New-Object System.Object
    $employee | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Creation Time" -Value $(Get-date)
    $employee | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Employee ID" -Value $($i.ToString("D2"))
    $employees += $employee
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}


#Finally, use Export-Csv to export the data to a csv file
$employees | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "c:\temp\test\EmployeeList.csv"
```

the result is

```
Creation Time     Employee ID

2014/10/14 1530      1

2014/10/14 1530      2

2014/10/14 1532      1

2014/10/14 1532      2
```

how can add the header...for examples

```
report<--title

Creation Time       Employee ID

2014/10/14 1530      1

2014/10/14 1530      2

2014/10/14 1532      1

2014/10/14 1532      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible using `Export-Csv` cmdlet. You have to read the file into temp variable, write the header line and add csv content:

```powershell
$csvPath = "c:\temp\test\EmployeeList.csv"
$eList = gc $csvPath
echo "report<--title" > $csvPath
$eList >> $csvPath
```